# How to init a UIView with different drawRect method in interface builder?

Tags: ios, uiview, interface-builder

Suppose I am using interface builder to draw a `xib` file which contains a `UIView`.

This view can be a circle or a polygon, but all other stuff in it are the same just the shapes are different. How could I do this within one `UIView` subclass? So that I could load a circle when displaying the nib when I want a circle and I could also load a polygon from the nib when I want a polygon.

Now I am using subclasses for the `UIView` so that I have a `Circle` class and a `Polygon` class. But to load any of them from the nib file I probably need to create another `xib` file to let each file contain a `UIView` subclass.

--UPDATED:

For example, I have a `UITableView` which uses a `CellView` as `UITableViewCell`. `CellView` is initialized from a nib file but also has a customized class implementation. Then inside `CellView` there is a `ShapeView` which displays different shapes, it could be a circle or a polygon. 'ShapeView' also has a customized implementation but I am not using another nib file to create it now. I want that when `CellView` is loaded `ShapeView` will be loaded with some parameters passed in so that it will display the correct shape.

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward way would be to have a `UIView` subclass that has a shape property. Something like this:

```
typedef enum ShapeType {
    ST_Circle,
    ST_Square,
    ST_Polygon
};

@class ShapeView : UIView {
}

@property ShapeType shape;

@end
```

And in the `-drawRect` method, just check the `shape` before drawing.

Alternatively, you could have a property that is the number of sides of a polygon. You could use 0 or 1 to mean circle. In your `-drawRect` method, draw the polygon based on the number of sides.

If you want to be able to set the property in Interface Builder, you could set the view's tag and translate that into the shape type (or number of sides) in `-awakeFromNib`, for example.

Comment: Does Cocoa init the children views before initializing its parent view or the opposite? In your example if I want to init the ShapeView using a Circle type, do I just init the ShapeView instance in the init method of its parent view and pass in the shapeType information? See my update.

Comment: I don't know the order of initialization. But you have several opportunities to do these sorts of things. You could do them in the `[-UITableView awakeFromNib:]` method, or `-viewDidLoad`. But why not get the shape from the data source for each cell? That seems like the most natural way to do it.